# Remove VS DB deployment script dependency on server name

Tags: sql, visual-studio, deployment, dbproj

When I deploy dbproj to SQL script and try to run it on another computer I get an error:

> The server name in the build script SOMENAME does not match the name of the target server ANOTHERNAME. Verify whether your database project settings are correct and whether your build script is up to date.

There are such lines generated in the script:

```
IF (@@servername != 'MYNAME')
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'The server name in the build script %s does not match the name of the target server %s. Verify whether your database project settings are correct and whether your build script is up to date.', 16, 127,N'MYNAME',@@servername) WITH NOWAIT
    RETURN
END
```

Is there any way to allow SQL deployment script to run on any server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution: I just have to go to `Project Properties -> Deploy -> Edit Deployment Configuration File` and uncheck `GenerateDeployStateChecks` checkbox. After that any mention of my server name disappear in deployment script.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't see and option for "GenerateDeployStateChecks" to uncheck. I am using VS2010 Ultimate.

Comment: @Rob, strange, I use the same version... You can find this option in `Properties\Database.sqldeployment`.